# in XACML(eXtensible Acces control markup language)

Tags: xacml

I am a student in Uni-Siegen.

For two weeks I am trying to define the communication between PDP and the PAP, but I do not know how to do it.

I would like to do it in java. What APIs can help me? Forget someone has a sample code and how to configure `exclipse`.

Comment: There is no pre-defined communication between a PDP and a PAP. This is not part of the specification. Different implementations (SunXACML, ATT, Axiomatics) have different ways of doing it.

Comment: hello are you one example the communication with sunXACML?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SunXACML api to build PDP and PEP. Create a blank java project in eclipse and add SunXACML jar in your project's build path. Then follow the following guide to implement a simple PDP and PEP in JAVA. Then test them using some XACML policies.

http://sunxacml.sourceforge.net/guide.html